# After grouping magento collection, the page became blank

Tags: magento-1.9

after running the following code:

```
$newCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setFlag('product_children', true);

$newCollection->getSelect()->where('link_table.parent_id', array('in' => $productIds));
$newCollection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

when using `foreach` or `count`, the page became blank. Anyone familiar with this case?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `link_table` should be `main_table`. Other than that, you could always use `echo $newCollection->getSelect();` to print the query and try it directly on the database to check if it yields any results, maybe the query is wrong.

Comment: The query is correct, it should be `link_table` and it returns a collection object. but when used on `foreach` or `count` the page became blank.

Comment: OK, my bad :) Could you post the other code you're using? Also, is there anything in the logs? If you get a blank page, there will most likely be a log entry in the Apache or Nginx server logs.

Comment: magento logs are not showing any error. also enabled error loggin in index.php but it's still blank.